# HttpOnly cookies aren't set in browser Angular 17/ Springboot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cookies, httponly

I am encountering an issue with cookies in my Angular application. Despite correctly configuring my backend to set cookies with the HttpOnly flag and allowing CORS with credentials, the cookies are not being set or received in the frontend. I have verified that the cookies are being set in the backend using Postman and that the withCredentials option is set to true in my Angular HTTP requests. I have also checked for errors in the browser console and network tab, but I cannot find any obvious issues. Has anyone encountered a similar problem with Angular and cookies, and if so, how did you resolve it? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

This is Springboot code:

```
public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword()
                )
        );
        var user = repository.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow();
        System.out.println("User authorities: " + user.getAuthorities());
        System.out.println("User role: " + user.getRole());

        if (user.isBlocked()) {
            throw new LockedException("User is blocked");
        }
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        var refreshToken = jwtService.generateRefreshToken(user);
        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("accessToken", jwtToken)
                .httpOnly(true)
                .secure(false)
                .sameSite("None")
                .path("/")
                .maxAge(cookieExpiry)
                .build();
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString());
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .accessToken(jwtToken)
                .refreshToken(refreshToken)
                .build();

    }
```

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization", "Cookie")
                .exposedHeaders(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE)
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

and this is the authService in Angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
 

  authenticate(uname: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const formData = { uname, password };

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8089/auth/authenticate', formData, {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers,
    });
  }
}
```

- I've created a HttpInterceptor class :

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const re1 = '/assets';
        const re2 = '/auth/logout';
        const re3 = '/auth/authenticate';
        
        if (request.url.search(re1) === -1
            && request.url.search(re2) === -1
            && request.url.search(re3) === -1
        ) {
            request = request.clone({
                withCredentials: true
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

I searched in github, stakoverflow, chatgpt, oracle, every possible place